# Программный клик по Flash баннеру

Tags: jquery, flash, javascript

В связи с некоторыми обстоятельствами появилась необходимость программно кликать по флеш баннеру (то есть без участия пользователя). Пробовал кликать по координатам с помощью чистого js, также перепробовал все возможные вариации вызова клика с помощью jQuery. Ничего не дает необходимого результата. Если кто-то встречался с данной проблемой буду рад любым советам ).

Comment: дайте угадаю, вы решили заработать на кликах, но без собственного участия?))

Comment: нет не угадали )

Comment: Вроде действительно это не обойти. Может тогда скажете зачем вам это надо? А мы вам поможем как обойти

Comment: Суть в том что мне необходимо получить конечную ссылку. То есть ссылку на которую попадет пользователь если кликнет по флеш банеру. Все это я делаю в хроме в режиме с --disable-web-security из под расширения для браузера. Так что если есть какая-то нестандартная идея то я буду рад ее услышать.

Comment: --disable-web-security из под расширения для браузера. 

Т.е. вы пишите не сайт, а расширение? А для себя или для всех? Просто если первое, то возможностей куда больше

Comment: А что если отслеживать все переходы со страницы? И отслеживать все нажатия на флэш. Если вовремя перехода было нажатие на флэш, значит его вызвал флэш). А переходы вроде отследить можно, не помню правда как

Comment: Человеческий фактор исключен. Это нужно получать в автоматическом режиме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Политика безопасности запрещает это делать.

Comment: Спасибо, по поводу политики безопасности знаю.